# Weighted routing over kubernetes services

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

I have one master service and multiple slave services. The master service continuously polls a topic using subscriber from Google PubSub. The Slave services are REST APIs. Once the master service receives a message, it delegates the message to a slave service. Currently I'm using ClusterIP service in Kubernetes. Some of my requests are long running and some are pretty short.

I happen to observe that sometimes if there's a short running request while a long running request is in process, it has to wait until the long running request to finish even though many pods are available without serving any traffic. I think it's due to the round robin load balancing. I have been trying to find a solution and looked into approaches like setting up external HTTP load balancer with ingress and internal HTTP load balancer. But I'm really confused about the difference between these two and which one applies for my use case. Can you suggest which of the approaches would solve my use case?

Answer (score 12):

#### TL;DR

assuming you want 20% of the traffic to go to `x` service and the rest 80% to `y` service. create 2 ingress files for each of the 2 targets, **with same host name**, the only difference is that one of them will carry the following **ingress annotations**: [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary)

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true" #--> tell the controller to not create a new vhost

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: "20" #--> route here 20% of the traffic from the existing vhost
```

---

#### WHY & HOW TO

weighted routing is a bit beyond the `ClusterIP`. as you said yourself, its time for a new player to enter the game - an [ingress controller](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress).

this is a k8s abstraction for a [`load balancer`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/load-balancing/) - a powerful server sitting in front of your app and routing the traffic between the `ClusterIP`s.

[install ingress controller on gcp cluster](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke)

once you have it installed and running, use its **canary** feature to perform a weighted routing. this is done using the following annotations:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-svc
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: "20"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: echo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

[here](https://www.elvinefendi.com/2018/11/25/canary-deployment-with-ingress-nginx.html) is the full guide.

#### External vs internal load balancing

(this is the relevant definition from google cloud docs but the concept is similar among other cloud providers)

> GCP's load balancers can be divided into external and internal load
> balancers. External load balancers distribute traffic coming from the
> internet to your GCP network. Internal load balancers distribute
> traffic within your GCP network.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview

Comment: I have come across readiness probes in Kubernetes which can be used to set pods as unready. If pods are unready they would be removed from the service. So, the new requests will be assigned to pods that are ready. How nginx ingress based load-balancing compares to that?

Comment: @backprop k8s simply wont remove the old pods before the new pods are marked as ready. this is an internal k8s matter which has nothing to do with the ingress. and as a remark- if my previous post answered your question you should accept my answer. [see how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: is this really the "official" way to do it?
I'm asking because there's this exact question in the CKAD exam and I'm not sure what they want as an answer, because neither the documentation nor the linux foundation slides contain an explanation on how to do it

Comment: @harrisonfooord https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary
thanks for pointing out I will add the link to my answer for more claruty